# Kafka Producer not producing through gunicorn and supervisor

Tags: python, django, apache-kafka, gunicorn, kafka-producer-api

I'm facing an odd situation because i can't seem to make my Kafka Producer work through my normal application flow. So in my `settings.py` file I create a global producer by calling  this function:

```
def init_producer(broker_url, delivery_timeout, retry_interval):
    try:
        return Producer(
            {
                "bootstrap.servers": broker_url,
                "delivery.timeout.ms": delivery_timeout,
                "request.timeout.ms": retry_interval,
            }
        )
    except Exception as exception:
        logger.error(
            f"Couldn't connect to broker {broker_url} because of exception {exception}"
        )
```

and then I do this in `settings` file :

```
producer = init_producer(
    KAFKA_BROKER_URL, KAFKA_DELIVERY_TIMEOUT, KAFKA_RETRY_INTERVAL
)
```

After that I then have a `post_save` signal in my model that runs the producing message when an instance of my model is saved in the database:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def update_report(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    produce_message(instance.id)
```

Then in my `produce_message` file I do the following:

```
def produce_message(instance_id):
    try:
        data = json.dumps(
            {
                "id": instance_id,
                "client": CLIENT,
                "database": "NAME",
            }
        )
        producer.produce(
            KAFKA_REPORT_TOPIC,
            data.encode("utf-8"),
            on_delivery=report_transaction_handler,
        )
        producer.poll(1)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.log(
            "MONITORING",
            f"Error {error} on producing message for Instance {instance_id}",
        )
```

My handler function does the following:

```
def report_model_handler(err, msg):
    """Called once for each message produced to indicate delivery result.
    Triggered by poll() or flush()."""
    if err is not None:
        value = simplejson.loads(msg.value().decode())
        logger.log(
            "MONITORING",
            f"Couldn't produce message {msg.value()} to topic {KAFKA_REPORT_TOPIC}",
        )
    else:
        logger.info(f"Message delivered to {msg.topic()} [{msg.partition()}]")
```

So now that i have given context here comes the odd part. When I run this through my app normal loop , that is when I do an action that then creates or updates an instance of MyModel the messages aren't sent to kafka topic but if I go inside my deployed on container on Google cloud platform run a shell and call that function by hand it sends the message to the consumer ( that is another separated app ). This only happens when I run everything through gunicorn + supervisor. in my local setup if I run everything through runserver everything works fine. Bellow I will also list my supervisor + gunicorn setup.

supervisor:

```
[program:django]
command=gunicorn --config settings/gunicorn.py settings.wsgi
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

gunicorn:

```
# Configuration file for gunicorn.
# See http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html for details.
import multiprocessing
from os import environ

port = environ.get("APP_PORT", 80)
bind = ["0.0.0.0:{}".format(port)]
limit_request_line = 64 * 2**10  # 16KB
workers = environ.get("APP_WORKERS", (2 * multiprocessing.cpu_count()) + 1)
worker_class = "gthread"
timeout = 120
graceful_timeout = 120
preload_app = True
worker_tmp_dir = "/dev/shm"
max_requests = 1000
max_requests_jitter = 50
loglevel = "error"
```

Can someone help me with this situation?

I already checked that the global producer connects to the kafka broker and that my post_save signal is called

Comment: So after a while I found out that this is because of the behavior of gunicorn and kafka C library libdkafka. because gunicorn launches a master process and then forks it to child processes that don't share memory and resources between them they cant have access to the global producer because kafka producer mantains open connections to the broker and stores data in memory. my suggestion to everyone that is seing this post in the future would be to try to create an async producer or create a kafka producer in the celery worker.

Comment: you can also try to override a producer variable in gunicorn.py using post_fork function to create a producer for each worker